# Magento 2.3 : How to set qty for multiple sources (Multi source inventory) programmatically

Tags: product, save, magento2.3, qty, multi-source-inventory

I have a site with 3 inventory sources. I want to add and update product inventory to each source by product sku. 
Please help me

Comment: For anybody searching for a solution, the most correct one that I've found was this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262851/magento-2-3-update-source-stock#answer-262873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know you guys get solution or not but here you go.

Here is the solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262873/49826

Comment: Sorry, it is not working

Comment: What error did you get Did you try to wrap process into try cactch ?

Comment: Also here's another may be it should work for you as it accepted answer :) https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262873/49826

Comment: Yes, the link works. Thank you so much Vivek.

Answer (score 1):

I just use API call to get the stock created or updated. code is following:

```
$access_token = '4v81lfihtkqanfdr6798zj352qyuyx1x';

$url = 'http://magento2.local/index.php/rest/V1/inventory/source-items';

$ch = curl_init($url);

$body = json_encode(['sourceItems' =>[
        ['source_code' => 'default', 'sku' => '24-MB01', 'quantity'=>555, 'status'=>1],
        ['source_code' => 'la', 'sku' => '24-MB01', 'quantity' => 222, 'status' => 1],
        ['source_code' => 'default', 'sku' => '24-MB04', 'quantity'=>444, 'status'=>1],
        ['source_code' => 'la', 'sku' => '24-MB04', 'quantity' => 111, 'status' => 1],
        ['source_code' => 'default', 'sku' => '24-MB03', 'quantity'=>333, 'status'=>1],
        ['source_code' => 'la', 'sku' => '24-MB03', 'quantity' => 111, 'status' => 1],
]]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: it is working fine only when we keep $access_token as static, if we generate it dynamically using (rest/V1/integration/admin/token) with curl method then it gives following error {"message":"The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_InventoryApi::source"}}

Comment: any idea that why it is giving authorized error for dynamic token?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SourceItemsSaveInterface interface for these purposes: https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/InventoryApi/Api/SourceItemsSaveInterface.php

```
interface SourceItemsSaveInterface
{
    /**
     * Save Multiple Source item data
     *
     * @param \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface[] $sourceItems
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Validation\ValidationException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException
     */
    public function execute(array $sourceItems): void;
}
```

And pass an array of \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface[] as a parameter, each source item represents inventory of specific product on specific source.

Comment: I have tried the following but it is not working
  $sourceInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface')->create();
  $sourceItems[] = ['sku'=>'00001','source_code'=>'source1',"quantity"=> 50,"status"=> 1];
  $sourceItems[] = ['sku'=>'00001','source_code'=>'source2',"quantity"=> 40,"status"=> 1];
  $sourceItems[] = ['sku'=>'00001','source_code'=>'source3',"quantity"=> 20,"status"=> 1];
  $sourceInterface->execute($sourceItems);

Comment: what you are doing is trying to save an array of data: ['sku'=>'00001','source_code'=>'source1',"quantity"=> 50,"status"=> 1] but an array of \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface[] objects should be provided

Comment: Also tried this
$sourceItem =  $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterfaceFactory')->create();
$sourceItem->setSourceCode('source1');
$sourceItem->setSku('00001');
$sourceItem->setQuantity(30);
$sourceItem->setStatus(1);

$sourceItems[] = $sourceItem;
$sourceInterface->execute($sourceItems);

Comment: Create object of SourceItemInterface and set values like QTY, Source etc and pass as an array like this $this->sourceItemsSave->execute([$sourceItem]);

Comment: @Arshad  as per last comment we can add one source data. how to save multiple at once