# Magento 2.3 Update Source Stock

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.0

Im currently creating a module that should update product quantity per source, based on SKU. Im using `Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface` and `Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemsInterface`.

Im trying to use the `execute()` function from `SourceItemsSaveInterface` but it expects parameter: `\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface[] $sourceItems`.

What's unclear to me, is how to get that parameter from the `SourceItemInterface` and what kind of data it should be.

Currently it gives me the below error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventoryApi\Model\SourceItemValidatorChain::validate() must implement interface Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface, array given....`

Using below code:

```
<?php
namespace <vendor>/<module>;

use Magento\InventoryApi\Api;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data;

class Temp
{
protected $_sourceItemsSaveInterface;

protected $_sourceItemInterface;

public function __construct(
    Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface $sourceItemsSaveInterface,
    Data\SourceItemInterface $sourceItemInterface
)
{
    $this->_sourceItemsSaveInterface = $sourceItemsSaveInterface;
    $this->_sourceItemInterface = $sourceItemInterface;
}

public function testFunction() {
    $sourceItemInterface = $this->_sourceItemInterface;

    $sourceItemInterface->setSourceCode('source');
    $sourceItemInterface->setSku('12345678');
    $sourceItemInterface->setQuantity(50);
    $sourceItemInterface->setStatus(1);

    $array = array(
        'sourceItems' => array('source_code' => 'source', 'sku' => '12345678', 'quantity'=>50, 'status'=>1)
    );

    $this->_sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute($array);

    //I need to know what kind of parameter/data should be set in execute() function
}
}
```

Comment: as far as I see you should pass an array of sourceItems (i.e. objects of type `\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface)` to the execute method. What is your code which gives that error?

Comment: @HelgeB see my edit in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create sourceItem objects, therefore I have injected a factory for that in your constructor. You can use the following code - it should work for you.
**since the constructor has changes, you might need to remove the corresponding generated file for your class**

```
<?php
namespace <vendor>/<module>;

use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterfaceFactory;

class Temp
{
   protected $_sourceItemsSaveInterface;

   protected $_sourceItemFactory;

   public function __construct(
       SourceItemsSaveInterface $sourceItemsSaveInterface,
       SourceItemInterfaceFactory $sourceItemFactory
   )
   {
       $this->_sourceItemsSaveInterface = $sourceItemsSaveInterface;
       $this->_sourceItemFactory = $sourceItemFactory;
   }

   public function testFunction() {

       //create the sourceItem using the factory
       $sourceItem = $this->_sourceItemFactory->create();
       $sourceItem->setSourceCode('source');
       $sourceItem->setSku('12345678');
       $sourceItem->setQuantity(50);
       $sourceItem->setStatus(1);

       //pass the sourceItem as an array element, you can add more source items in the same call as further array elements
       $this->_sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
   }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: you can add more source items in the same call as further array elements?? how we can pass array of multiple source?